# Spacing for cells in LazyVGrid are not the same on all sides

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a LazyVGrid, and I am trying to make the spacing for all the cells in the grid to be equal. However, the cells keep touching the edges of the screen, and I am struggling to make it equal to the rest of the spacing for each cell. This is how it looks:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem](repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 2)) {
                    ForEach(0..<6) { selection in
                        SelectionView()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("The Deep End")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

struct SelectionView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
                
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
        .background(Color.green)
        .cornerRadius(15)
    }
}
```

Comment: try to put `padding` to your Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo code specifying all available spacing options to 20.

```
ScrollView {
    //                                                             VV horizontal spacing    VV vertical spacing
    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem](repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20), count: 2), spacing: 20) {
        ForEach(0..<6) { selection in
            SelectionView()
        }
    }
    .padding(20) // << surrounding spacing
}
```